# Recursive Get-ChildItem and merging files within the same directory

Tags: powershell, foreach, merge, get-childitem

I am trying to perform a recursive search that will merge files together into a single file within the directory the file was found.  Find files named Dexis_Conflit_(*).dat and merge, or create into a file named dexis.dat. The .dat files are plain text.  There are thousands of folders that I need to find and merge these files in.  I have a basic PowerShell code that finds all of the files and their corresponding folders, but I cannot figure out how to merge them all into a single file within the correct directories.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Include "dexis_conflict_(*).dat" -Path D:\apps\dexis\data -Recurse -OutVariable DEXIS.dat
```

I have tried using Out-File, Set-Content, Add-Content, and foreach but I cannot figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:  Most 95% of the folders will already have a dexis.dat file in it.  All "conflict" files need to be merged into the main dexis.dat file.  Those folders that do not have a dexis.dat file, it will need to be created and the conflict file merged into it.

Comment: These `.dat` files, what actually are they? Are these plain text files?

Comment: is `"dexis_conflict_(*).dat"` an actual wildcard, or is that the literal file name?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon these are plain text files, but with a .dat extension

Comment: @AbrahamZinala that is a wildcard; however, using the actual number 1, 2, 3, 4, etc yeilds the same results but only those specific numbers files.

Comment: The expected result is one `DEXIS.dat` file per folder inside `D:\apps\dexis\data` ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon that is correct.  If there is a "conflict" file it needs to be merged into the main dexis.dat file.  IF for some reason there is no file by that name it would need to create and merge into dexis.dat.

Comment: This last comment implies there might be a `dexis.dat` file in place in the folders, in which case, this just be clarified in the question instead of comments

Comment: Correct, I edited the main post.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, there are plenty of ways to go about this using PowerShell so here's my take:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\apps\dexis\data" -Filter "dexis_conflict_(*).dat" -File -Recurse | 
    ForEach-Object -Begin {
        $saveTo = "DEXIS.dat"
    } -Process {
        $parentPath = Resolve-Path $_.PSParentPath -Relative 
        $jointPath  = Join-Path -Path $parentPath -ChildPath $saveTo
            if (-not (Test-Path -Path $jointPath)) {
                New-Item -Path $jointPath | Out-Null  
            }
        Get-Content -LiteralPath $_.FullName | Add-Content -LiteralPath $jointPath 
    }
```

Given that your files are just plain text files, there shouldn't be a need to use a specific file encoding such as bytes, but there is still that option if needed. Other than that, the rest is pretty simple. Using `Resolve-Path` we can can get rid of the unwanted prepended text PowerShell adds to the parent path. Then, using `Join-Path` we can create the file path of `.\.\DEXIS.dat` which we can test against. This is doable since PowerShell processes the files in each directory one at a time before moving onto the next sub-folder.

So...

- Test to see if `dexis.dat` exists, and if not, create the file.
- If the file does exist just append the content of each `dexis_conflict_(*).dat` file  to it using `Add-Content`.

Now, every directory should have a `DEXIS.dat` file with merged content from file names of `dexis_conflict_(*).dat`.